# How to add values of a .csv file to arrays in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, csv

Several values for temperatures, voltage and time are stored in my .csv file.
My goal is to get those different values for the temperature, voltage and time from the .csv file into a matrix in Matlab. [The saved data in the .csv file has the following form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR2my.jpg):

I have tried multiple commands and script, with the one below I came closets to achieving my goal.

```
S = fileread("example.csv");
S(S == '"') = [];                                                                               
fmt = '%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f';
A = textscan(S, fmt, 'HeaderLines', 1, 'Delimiter', ',', 'CollectOutput', true);
Data = cell2mat(A);
```

How can I get the data in a matrix?

---

Here is the content of example.csv as text:

```
Time,"T4","T2","T3","T4","T5","T6","T7","T8","Voltage"
00:00:00,"36.934","23.625","23.080","14.022","14.007","22.374","22.094","19.495","0.748"
00:00:01,"37.033","23.611","23.088","14.022","14.026","22.371","22.095","19.474","0.757"
00:00:02,"37.095","23.596","23.066","14.022","14.008","22.371","22.091","19.422","0.747"
00:00:03,"37.180","23.575","23.070","14.027","14.019","22.368","22.092","19.385","0.741"
00:00:04,"37.286","23.557","23.067","14.020","14.020","22.361","22.081","19.352","0.740"
00:00:05,"37.377","23.542","23.057","14.024","14.024","22.350","22.074","19.308","0.712"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the puzzle:

According to your comments, the Excel sheet should look as in the following image:
[image]

When saving the from Excel to CSV the text of `example.csv` is:

```
"Time,""T4"",""T2"",""T3"",""T4"",""T5"",""T6"",""T7"",""T8"",""Voltage"""
"00:00:00,""36.934"",""23.625"",""23.080"",""14.022"",""14.007"",""22.374"",""22.094"",""19.495"",""0.748"""
"00:00:01,""37.033"",""23.611"",""23.088"",""14.022"",""14.026"",""22.371"",""22.095"",""19.474"",""0.757"""
"00:00:02,""37.095"",""23.596"",""23.066"",""14.022"",""14.008"",""22.371"",""22.091"",""19.422"",""0.747"""
"00:00:03,""37.180"",""23.575"",""23.070"",""14.027"",""14.019"",""22.368"",""22.092"",""19.385"",""0.741"""
"00:00:04,""37.286"",""23.557"",""23.067"",""14.020"",""14.020"",""22.361"",""22.081"",""19.352"",""0.740"""
"00:00:05,""37.377"",""23.542"",""23.057"",""14.024"",""14.024"",""22.350"",""22.074"",""19.308"",""0.712"""
```

But it could also look like the following one:
[image]

When saving the from Excel to CSV the text of `example.csv` is:

```
Time  ,"""T1""","""T2""    ","""T3""    ","""T4""    ","""T5""    ","""T6""    ","""T7""    ","""T8""    ","""Voltage"""
00:00:00,"""36.934""","""23.625""","""23.080""","""14.022""","""14.007""","""22.374""","""22.094""","""19.495""","""0.748"""
00:00:01,"""37.033""","""23.611""","""23.088""","""14.022""","""14.026""","""22.371""","""22.095""","""19.474""","""0.757"""
00:00:02,"""37.095""","""23.596""","""23.066""","""14.022""","""14.008""","""22.371""","""22.091""","""19.422""","""0.747"""
00:00:03,"""37.180""","""23.575""","""23.070""","""14.027""","""14.019""","""22.368""","""22.092""","""19.385""","""0.741"""
00:00:04,"""37.286""","""23.557""","""23.067""","""14.020""","""14.020""","""22.361""","""22.081""","""19.352""","""0.740"""
00:00:05,"""37.377""","""23.542""","""23.057""","""14.024""","""14.024""","""22.350""","""22.074""","""19.308""","""0.712"""
```

You can read both using the following code sample:

```
S = fileread("example.csv");
S(S == '"') = [];
S(S == ' ') = []; %Remoove spaces (just in case...)
fmt = '%f:%f:%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f';
%A = textscan(S, fmt, 'HeaderLines', 1, 'Delimiter', ',', 'CollectOutput', true);
A = textscan(S, fmt, 'HeaderLines', 1, 'CollectOutput', true);
Data = cell2mat(A);
```

Result:

```
Data =

         0         0         0   36.9340   23.6250   23.0800   14.0220   14.0070   22.3740   22.0940   19.4950    0.7480
         0         0    1.0000   37.0330   23.6110   23.0880   14.0220   14.0260   22.3710   22.0950   19.4740    0.7570
         0         0    2.0000   37.0950   23.5960   23.0660   14.0220   14.0080   22.3710   22.0910   19.4220    0.7470
         0         0    3.0000   37.1800   23.5750   23.0700   14.0270   14.0190   22.3680   22.0920   19.3850    0.7410
         0         0    4.0000   37.2860   23.5570   23.0670   14.0200   14.0200   22.3610   22.0810   19.3520    0.7400
         0         0    5.0000   37.3770   23.5420   23.0570   14.0240   14.0240   22.3500   22.0740   19.3080    0.7120
```

Comment: However, when I use the `readtable` command, it does not automatically detect the table as in your explanation. When I use it, all data just gets stored in one column with all the apostrophes and commas. It looks as follows:
`'00:00:00,"36.934","23.625","23.080","14.022","14.007","22.374","22.094","19.495","0.748"'
'00:00:01,"37.033","23.611","23.088","14.022","14.026","22.371","22.095","19.474","0.757"'`

I am using an older version of Matlab, namely R2018a, might this be a problem?

Comment: I don't think the problem involves version R2018a. Since you posted the CSV file as an image, I can't know the true content of the file. I edited your post, and added the data I assumed is the content of the file. Try: copy and paste the text from the post to example.csv, and tell me if it's working.

Comment: The content of the .csv file is exactly as you described in the edit, so I do not think that is the problem.

Unfortunately, I tried your script with the data that you used, that did not work either. I had the same problem as before where all the values ended up into the same matrix column. 
Additionally, I got the following error and warning:
`Warning: Variable names were modified to make them valid MATLAB identifiers. The original names are saved in the VariableDescriptions property. 
Error using read_data2 (line 11)
Unrecognized variable name 'Time'.`

Comment: What is the size of `T` after `T = readtable('example.csv');` ? (like `6x10 table`). Are you using Windows, Linux or Mac? Are you moving the `csv` file between Windows and Linux or Mac?

Comment: The size of `T` is `3x1` (3 rows, 1 column), for every second a new row (0 to 2 seconds).
It looks as follows for one row:
`'00:00:02,"37.095","23.596","23.066","0.747"'`

I am only using Windows.

Comment: Where is the row `Time,"T4","T2","T3","T4","T5","T6","T7","T8","Voltage"`? not part of `T`? Are you sure `example.csv` file is a text file? What text editor are you using?

Comment: For this one I only used the data from your example, so only: `Time,"T1","T2","T3"`.

I am measuring several temperatures and a voltage in a laboratory setup, these measured values are then saved in a .csv file in Excel in the way as I described earlier, however, the file is not edited in Excel orso.

Comment: Try to create a text file using a text editor like notepad... I think what your are showing me is the **Excel** sheet and not the text content of the CSV file. Please open the CSV file using a text editor, and post the content in your question.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, what can be seen in the image attached in my question is a screenshot of the excelsheet. However, I do not understand what you mean with showing you the content of the actual .csv file as the content is exactly the same as in the image and the same as the text that you editted my question with.

Comment: Also, I opened the content of the .csv file with Notepad instead of Excel and saved it as a .txt file. I tried to open this new `example.txt` file in Matlab with your code where i changed `T = readtable('example.csv');` to `T = readtable('example.txt');`.

This did not work, unfortunately. I received the same error as earlier: 
`Warning: Variable names were modified to make them valid MATLAB identifiers. The original names are saved in the VariableDescriptions property. 
Error using read_data2 (line 11)
Unrecognized variable name 'Time'.`

Comment: I think I know what you are trying to do. I updated my post.

Comment: Can't you just open the file `example.csv` using Notepad, and copy and paste the content as text into the body of your original question???